# Unset first element from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am having a php `SESSION` array like below:

```
[image] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1475141244.jpg
            [2] => 1475141245.jpg
            [3] => 1475141245_1.jpg
            [4] => 1475141246.jpg
        )
```

According to the given key, I want to unset key/value from this array.

I tried it something like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['key'])){ 
  $delkey = $_POST['key'];
  foreach ($_SESSION['image'] as $k => $v) {
    if ($delkey == $v) {      
      $imgkey = array_search($v, $_SESSION['image']);
      if($imgkey) unset($_SESSION['image'][$imgkey]);
    }    
  }
}
```

But my problem is I can not unset first item from this array. For other keys its not problem for me.

Can anybody tell me whats the reason for this?

Comment: What do your mean by `first item`???

Comment: @FrayneKonok, first item mean `[1] => 1475141244.jpg`

Comment: Why are you doing an `array_search()`? You already have the key in `$k`.

Comment: you can use `in_array()` and `unset()`..

Comment: @FrayneKonok, can you show me an example

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy solution to unset the `$_SESSION`- Use the `in_array()` function to check the desire value is in the `$_SESSION` or not.

```
if(!empty($_POST['key'])){ 
    $delkey = $_POST['key'];
    if(in_array($delkey, $_SESSION['image'])){
        $imgkey = array_search($delkey, $_SESSION['image']);
        unset($_SESSION['image'][$imgkey ]);    
    }
}
```

Here is the [working example](https://3v4l.org/H7Gqm) with an array and creating post value.

I think this will help you. Let me know is it okey or not??

Comment: You can combine `array_keys` and `in_array` using `array_key_exists`.

Comment: O yes, I did't think about it, thanks for the information.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. NOTE: `$delkey` not have key it has the value of the array...

Comment: so just remove the `array_keys()` function from my answer and try. with that key using `array_search()`.

Comment: @user3733831, I update my answer. Check and let me know.

Comment: I checked it. but still it doesn't work... now I can't unset any element from the array..

Comment: What's the issue now? Can you explain a little??

Comment: OKEY let me create an example for you.

Comment: Yes, your demo is working.. but in my script.. it doesn't.. All other elements can unset except first element.. I don't know why..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124523/discussion-between-user3733831-and-frayne-konok).

Comment: Scanning the same array twice with `in_array()` then `array_search()`?  I wouldn't in one of my projects.

Answer (score 1):

**array_shift()** shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one element and moving everything down. All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be touched.

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$fruit = array_shift($stack);
print_r($stack);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
    [2] => raspberry
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
if (!empty($_POST['key'])){ 
  session_start();
  $delkey = $_POST['key'];
  foreach ($_SESSION['image'] as $k => $v) {
    if ($delkey == $v) {      
      $imgkey = array_search($v, $_SESSION['image']);
      if($imgkey) {
           unset($_SESSION['image'][$imgkey]);
        }
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try  `array_shift()`, for example : `array_shift($_SESSION['image']);`

I tried following code, it's worked.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['image'] = array(
            1 => '1475141244.jpg',
            2 => '1475141245.jpg',
            3 => '1475141245_1.jpg',
            4 => '1475141246.jpg',
        );
array_shift($_SESSION['image']);
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: This doesn't works because $_SESSION['image'] itself contains an array in it.